# Customize IntelliJ's name suggestions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I'd like IntelliJ to suggest specific patterns based on the type of the variable or return type for certain cases.

### Example

[image: Screenshot 1]

For example, I would like the first suggestion in this list to be `optionalDateTime`

### What I've tried

- Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java
- Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion
- Searched preferences for `name` and also for `suggest`, but none of the matches seems a likely candidate
- Searched SO, Jetbrains support and Google

### Question

Does anyone know how to customize the names IntelliJ suggests when completing variable and method names?

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed in upcoming 2017.3 (filed as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-178297)

Comment: Thank you! That would be great. How can I customize suggested names in general though? Is there a preference or can it be done with a plugin, if at all?

Comment: Such fine customizations are not possible with preferences, only with a plugin.

Comment: Got it. Lastly, do you know what this feature is called, specifically in the IntelliJ SDK? I've studied the docs but many nav options are greyed out, including `Part II - Architecture` --> `Features`: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html

Comment: I call it "variable/member name completion". It's just plain code completion, probably not deserving a mention in platform SDK (since it's JVM-specific). The completion is done in `JavaMemberNameCompletionContributor`, and it uses `JavaCodeStyleManager` to get the suggestions. `Optional` is currently hardcoded there.

Comment: As for grayed out items, we'll do something with them, thanks for reporting!